# How to properly pass dynamic 2-d array into a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I need to dynamically allocate a 2-d array in a function with `n` rows and `m` columns that are also has to be read from `input` function.

```
int main()
{
    int** matrix;
    int n, m;
    input(matrix, &n, &m);
    return 0;
} 

void input(int** matrix, int* n, int* m) {
    if (scanf("%d", n) == 1 && getchar() == '\n') {
        if (*n <= 0) {
            error = 1;
        }
    }
    if (error == 0) {
        if (scanf("%d", m) == 1 && getchar() == '\n') {
            if (*m <= 0) {
                error = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (error == 0) {
        matrix = (int**)calloc(*n, sizeof(int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            matrix[i] = (int*)calloc(*m, sizeof(int));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < *n && error == 0; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *m && error == 0; j++) {
                if (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) == 1) {
                }
                else {
                    error = 1;
                } 
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < *m; j++) {
                printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

It scans and prints values properly, but if I try to interact with `matrix` outside this function or in another function (e.g. `output(int** matrix, int *n, int *m` that just prints all the values) I'll get memory error.
How do i suppose to fix that? (I need to keep double pointer).

Comment: The straightforward way is change `matrix` to a pointer to `int**` for update just like `n` and `m`. Why do you need to keep double pointer? Another way is eliminating the argument `matrix`, which is not useful, and have the function `input` return the newly allocated `int**`.

Comment: Is is the requirement of the task. At least, a formal parameters in the input function have to be same as they are right now.

Comment: The value of the `matrix` parameter is being ignored by the function, and `main` is calling it with an uninitialized value anyway.

Comment: You are  changing the value of the pointer matrix with the line: "matrix = ". You are not allocating at the address passed by the parameter matrix

Comment: One more way is treating the `int** matrix` as a pointer to a pointer (1D array) and using the 1D array to emulate 2D array like `array[rowIndex * width + colIndex]`

Comment: @IanAbbott The question is what do I have to change for the ```matrix``` parameter not being ignored.

Comment: If the formal parameters cannot be changed, it looks like it is expecting you to pass in the address of an `int *` and to use a linear (1-D) representation of the matrix.

Comment: What are your *exact* requirements?  I suspect you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: @IanAbbott Even if the parameters should be the same, nothing is said about the return value. Therefore there is a chance that returning the new array is allowed.

Comment: @IanAbbott ... but now it looks weird to have an ignored argument `matrix`. Using 1D representation looks better. But the arguments for `output` is weird anyway (I don't think `n` and `m` for that should be pointers), so it looks like having weird arguments shouldn't be cared here.

Comment: @MikeCAT Good point, but then there would be no need for the `matrix` parameter at all!

Comment: I can't use ```return``` as well. However, I guess I can use pointer to a pointer (1D array). It is only stated that I can't change function formal parameters and has to manipulate with arrays and corresponding values in the function (scan, print, memory allocating etc.).

Comment: Everything in C is pass-by-value, so any changes you make to a function parameter are local only to that function. Meaning any change you make to `matrix` in `input` is local only to that function. If you want changes to `matrix` to persist outside of `input`, you need to `return` it, or pass an address to `matrix` (`int***` type) and manipulate the memory space it points to. Or make `matrix` global. You say you can't `return` and you can't change the function signature? I guess making `matrix` global is your only option. Terrible requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `matrix` is not being used by the `input` function, and `main` is not passing any valid value for this parameter.

Since the return type of `input` is `void`, everything needs to be passed back to the caller via pointer arguments. The values for `n` and `m` are already being passed back by pointers, so the value of `matrix` also needs to be passed back by a pointer, like this:

```
    int* matrix;
    int n, m;
    input(&matrix, &n, &m);
```

Note that the type of the caller's `matrix` variable needed to be changed from `int**` to `int*`. This means that the matrix must be represented by a linear (1-D) array of `int`. Therefore, `input` needs to allocate the memory for the matrix as a single block holding an array of `int` and it needs to map the 2-D matrix element indices to a 1-D array index.

The allocation in `input` needs to be something like this:

```
        *matrix = calloc(*n * *m, sizeof(int));
```

and the matrix element at row `i` column `j` needs to be converted to a 1-D index like this: `(*matrix)[i * *m + j]` (where `*m` is the number of columns).

Other functions that are called on the same matrix need to do the same conversion from 2-D indices to a 1-D index. For example:

```
void output(const int *matrix, int n, int m) {
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
           printf("%d ", matrix[i * m + j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
    int* matrix;
    int n, m;
    input(&matrix, &n, &m);
    output(matrix, n, m);
```